# Has Canonical packaged the latest NVIDIA drivers (430.40) for the 2070 Super yet?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I've installed Ubuntu 19.04 on the new system I built this week (specs below), and I'm stuck in a login loop unless I boot with nomodeset.

Specs:

- Gigabyte X570 Aorus Master
- AMD Ryzen 7 3700x
- NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 Super
- Corsair MP600 1 TB
- Crucial Ballistix Sport Lt 3200 MHz 32 GB DDR4
- Corsair RM850x

I installed Ubuntu in a single 40 GB partition (with Windows 10 on the rest of the disk). From the latest I've read, it seems like a swap partition is no longer necessary most of the time (and that using a swapfile instead is now the default in Ubuntu). And I didn't create a separate /home partition because I'll be using this partition for development and won't be storing much in the way of personal files or media in Ubuntu.

I expect the issue is rooted in driver support for the 2070 Super, but I've also read that there are some issues with my processor and motherboard as well. Here's what I've tried so far:

- Updated motherboard BIOS to F5I (before installing Ubuntu). Verified that secure boot is not enabled.
- Updated all software with apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, and apt-get update again.
- Booted into the desktop environment with nomodeset.
- Looked for proprietary driver options in the Additional Drivers section of Software & Updates. None were found.
- Downloaded the latest Linux driver version (430.40) from NVIDIA's website, made the file executable (chmod 777), and ran it. Driver installation reported successful completion.
- Rebooted without nomodeset, but login loop issue persists.
- Verified

Things I haven't tried yet:

- Installing the drivers through PPA.
- Installing 18.04 instead.
- Uninstalling/disabling the Nouveau drivers.

Does anyone know about the state and/or roadmap of support for this hardware combination? Do I need to uninstall/disable the Nouveau drivers in order for the proprietary driver to be used? Or do I just need to be patient? In particular, are we still waiting for Canonical to package the latest drivers for the 2070 Super for distribution through the Additional Drivers tab?

Comment: PPA has all the newest drivers: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa & https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers But AMD 3000 series have issues. AMD has released UEFI/BIOS update but only some vendors have included those fixes, so far in their UEFI updates. AMD UEFI/BIOS update for Ryzen 3000 series
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ryzen-3000-BIOS-Update-Good

Comment: The easiest way is to install the driver from PPA.

Comment: Thank you both. Do I need to uninstall or disable the Nouveau drivers after installing the proprietary drivers via PPA? Will the proprietary drivers ever be released through the Additional Drivers tab, or only with the next major release?

Comment: Thank you for linking to "How do I install the Nvidia drivers?". Very helpful.

Comment: You should not have to uninstall Nouveau. If using nomodeset to boot, you will not need it once nVidia driver installed. With 19.10, nVidia driver will be installed if user selects that during install. Some additional discussion: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1826844?_ga=2.106297347.1216151408.1558561863-1544747127.1545400671

Comment: What it's already October 2019? My how time has flown :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Is that when we expect this to be resolved? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see now that 19.10 (due in October) is expected to include the proprietary drivers in the ISO.